# 503 service unavailable while trying to login through wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, login, cookies, 503-error

I have no access to my site on Wordpress from any laptop browser I have.
But it's possible to log in from other computers and I can access it from my phone.

In the laptop browser, I type aomy.nl/wp-login.php, and I receive 503 Service unavailable. I tried to remove all cookies, restart the browser, restart the computer. Tried to do the same in incognito page - same problem.

This is not my field, please, could someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to talk about it in public". Look at the error log of the server (usually located under `/var/log`), there will be a clear message saying what's wrong.

Comment: Your site appears to be working fine. What does this error page look like? Include a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone! I was lucky to find a problem.

It was a VPN application. My access was limited to certain country area. Vpn made me seeing as a user from outside this area.